# MySQL not starting On AWS (EC2- Ubuntu Instance)

Tags: mysql

I'm running Ubuntu instance at AWS (ES2). After upgrading the instance, I was not able to start MySQL. Before the upgrade, MySQL was working correctly.

`service mysql start` The output:

```
Authentication is required to start 'mysql.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start mysql.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.
```

I tried:
`systemctl status mysql.service`
The output:

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-10-12 17:22:21 UTC; 3h 12min ago
  Process: 3610 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status
  Process: 3591 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 12 17:22:21 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 12 17:22:24 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 12 17:22:24 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 12 17:22:24 ip-172-31-30-161 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

`mysql --version` The output:
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

`which mysql` The output: `usr/bin/mysql`

Also, I tried this: `mysql -u root -p` The output is:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I'm stuck and don't know where to go.

Note: I don't want to lose the old Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The main issue was the AWS instance run out of space. Once I removed the some files, I was able to re-run it again.